# How to test an angular web site when the computer where it is installed has no Internet access at all?

Tags: angular, testing, automated-tests

We have a web site installed on a computer that do not have an Internet access, but we're willing to test it by any mean of test units.

One of us tried *Protractor* and *Karma*, but tests are blocking as they are willing to complete their installation with some *Selenium* additional parts from the Internet, which is not available.

So eventually any test hangs and fails.

Do we have a way to succeed web testing if the computer running web site only holds *Angular* and a browser but no Internet access?

Comment: If I remember correctly Protractor checks if there are any new browser drivers available before running tests which could fail. Also, Protractor is deprecated, I recommend you move to something like Cypress.

Comment: Thanks for the advice of moving to Cypress. But can it run offline?